# what does "cod delusion" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I wonder what they mean by "cod delusion" as the title for this episode?
http://wsdownload.bbc.co.uk/learningenglish/pdf/2012/07/120719131651_120719_6min_dawkins_3.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a pun - Richard Dawkins' wrote a famous book about atheism titled "[The God delusion](http://www.amazon.co.uk/The-God-Delusion-Richard-Dawkins/dp/055277331X)", and cod is another type of fish.